# Especificar versão do Oracle Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, oracle

Hoje estamos trabalhando com duas versão do banco oracle 12c e 11g.
O desenvolvimento é realizado na versão 12c.

Ao utilizar o Entity Framework para realizar um `Count`, o mesmo está aplicando uma função que não existe na versão 11g `OUTER APPLY`.

Existe alguma maneira de configurar o entity para que ele entenda qual versão do oracle o banco está? Ou mesmo que seja setar para que sempre utilize a versão 11g?

Desde já obrigado.

Comment: Nele em si duvido, no *driver* do Oracle talvez tenha.

Comment: Qual é o erro apresentado, e qual é o código utilizado? (vale lembrar que tudo depende do `provider`)